# Why didn't Quria, Blade Transform, decide to introduce a Hive worm into its mind fluid?

Tags: destiny

An excerpt from the Books of Sorrow, Verse 4:9 "open your eye : go into it":

> Quria captured some worm larvae and began experimenting with them. Soon Quria, Blade Transform manifested religious tactics. By directing worship at the worms, Quria learned it could alter reality with mild ontopathogenic effects. Being an efficient machine, Quria manufactured a priesthood and ordered all its subminds to believe in worship. Then it set about abducting and killing dangerous organisms so it could bootstrap itself to Hive godhood. For some Vex reason, Quria never attempted to introduce worm larvae into its mind fluid.

Why would Quria not decide to combine the two? Its ability to quickly deduce the Sword Logic is a testament to its processing power and logical processes, so what was the reason for this decision? Was it concerned regarding the possibility of being overtaken by the Darkness associated with the worms, or was it something else?

Comment: Some Vex reason.

Comment: Are you asking whether Quria was indecisive,  or whether they chose against the worm? I'm going to guess the latter and edit your title to match. Feel free to revert the edit if that wasn't your in.

Comment: The verse simply states that it "never attempted to introduce" the worm larvae, so I'm not sure what the decisive action was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because it didn't want to be inflicted with the same curse that the hive has, which is to endlessly feed their worms or be eaten by them.